# InvalidStateError: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 11

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

can someone please tell me where im going wrong here?

```
window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB ||
window.mozIndexedDB;

if ('webkitIndexedDB' in window) {
    window.IDBTransaction = window.webkitIDBTransaction;
    window.IDBKeyRange = window.webkitIDBKeyRange;
}

var VULY_DB = {};
VULY_DB = {};
VULY_DB.db = null;

VULY_DB.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log(e);
};

VULY_DB.open = function() {
    var request = indexedDB.open(salt);


    request.onerror = request.onsuccess = function(e) { VULY_DB.onerror(request.error); };
    request.onsuccess = function(e) {
        VULY_DB.db = e.target.result;
        var db = VULY_DB.db;

        var store = db.createObjectStore("revisions", {keyPath: "id"});
    };
};

VULY_DB.open();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create objectStores in an onupgradeneeded method, not onsuccess.

See MDN's example under "Structuring the database":

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB

Answer (score 2):

You also generally do not need to use prefixed globals. I believe in recent versions of Chrome the -webkit prefix was dropped and you should just use the normal global variable.